# How can I append a new element (new node) in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I want to append a new input (new node) on clicking the button (plus). I implement this via `appendChild(input)`. New input appears on the screen and I can see it in *Developer Tools > Elements*, but **React does't see it**.

[Developer Tools > Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG54I.jpg)

[Developer Tools > React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebf88.jpg)

```
onClickPlus(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   let button = event.currentTarget;
   let input = button.previousSibling.cloneNode(true);
   let name = input.getAttribute("name").split(".");
   let newName = name[0] + '.' + (Number(name[1]) + 1);
   input.setAttribute("name", newName);
   let parent = button.parentNode;
   parent.appendChild(input);
   parent.appendChild(button);
}
```

How can I implent this properly?

Comment: Use state! https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html

Comment: React is not jquery!

Comment: @Maxwelll thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid manipulating the DOM "manually" as it will change the DOM tree and will affect the reconciliation process. This will result in a complete re-render of the react component and will affect performance considerably.

Instead I would use a state variable ej. "visible" that the click method would update on click.

```
onClickPlus(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   this.setState({visible: true})
}
```

If you need to render multiple input instances as the user  click on the + button, the best would be to have an array of this instances in the state.

```
constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {
        inputElements: []
     }
}

onClickPlus(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   this.setState({
    inputElements: this.state.inputElement.concat(newElementId)
   })
}
```

And iterate over the inputElement array at render time. This way you can also a have a - button that eliminates input fields.

For dynamic react forms with global state redux-form FieldArray are strongly recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I think you can't use 'push', mb 'concat'?

Comment: True. Push will not return a new array but concat will. Great point!